# Firebase - Using addValueEventListener in a Fragment doesn't work

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fragment

I am struggling with this problem for almost a week now trying everything out but I can't help myself... 
The fragment should just load the username from a node in the realtime Database. The code works perfectly in a normal Activity but it does not work in this fragment..
I think the listener is not properly working but i have no clue why :/
I hope someone can help me before i lost my mind...

Thanks in advance!!

The Realtime Database in Firebase looks like:

```
DatabaseName
    Users
        UID(Unique User ID)
            fullname
            username
```

######

Fragment class, just the conCreateView()

```
private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String currentUserID;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    username_et = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.profile_username);
    email_et = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.profile_email);
    change_btn = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.profile_change_btn);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    DatabaseReference mRef = mDatabase.getReference("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

    mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.e("Error","onDataChange fired!");
            String username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
            username_et.setText(username);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



    final String email = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
    email_et.setText(email);

    return rootview;
}
```

Comment: what is the error generate?

Comment: Can you please add you read database structure? And if you get an error, please paste it over here.

Comment: there is no error occuring... the code works finde except that the listener does not start. 
I just Log.e to check if the onDataChange method is called

Comment: @AlexMamo what du you mean by database structure? You can see it at the beginning of my post how the real time database looks like

Comment: Does it get to your Log.e? If not you should really add one inside the onCancelled to print any errors.

Comment: add your database

Comment: @AndréKool I put a Log.e into the onDataChanged() and onCancelled() but none of them print something out... The thing is that the code runs perfectly on a simple activity where i load the username in a TextView...arrgh!

Comment: Can you include that information in your question? It makes the question more specific. Also you should include your actual database instead of a representation of it.

Comment: Add a screenshot of y our database from Firebase Console.

Comment: I just figured out that it has to be a problem with my project.. created a new one and did the same thing and it works...

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing all your functionality in `onViewCreated` method and not in `onCreateView`. So performing setText or whatever method should be in `onViewCreated`

So in your case, just move this line of code from onCreateView to onViewCreated method-

```
DatabaseReference mRef = mDatabase.getReference("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.e("Error","onDataChange fired!");
        String username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
        username_et.setText(username);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});



final String email = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
email_et.setText(email);
```